# Typescript - Trying to call method on abstract base with derived type as parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, abstract

The abstract base has a method that takes a base/derived and performs something on it.
Seems like I'm missing something with the typing, trying to find out what.

Attempt 1:

```
abstract class Base {
  protected runFuncOnThis = (func: (baseOrDerived: Base) => void) => {
    func(this);
  };
}

class Derived extends Base {
  public doIt = () => {
    this.runFuncOnThis((derived: Derived) => { // ERROR HERE
      console.log(derived);
    });
  };
}
```

Error:
Argument of type '(derived: Derived) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(baseOrDerived: Base) => void'.
Types of parameters 'derived' and 'baseOrDerived' are incompatible.
Property 'doIt' is missing in type 'Base' but required in type 'Derived'.ts(2345)

Attempt 2:

```
abstract class Base2 {
  protected runFuncOnThis = <T extends Base2>(func: (baseOrDerived: T) => void) => {
    func(this); // ERROR HERE
  };
}

class Derived2 extends Base2 {
  public doIt = () => {
    this.runFuncOnThis((derived: Derived2) => {
      console.log(derived);
    });
  };
}
```

Error: Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
'this' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Base2'.ts(2345)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgg3gFAIIAOUA9hDvDgCYJQCuAdgGKuwDyLAKgBYBLMAB5eCHAA9qLOhmxgcAPgAUEIWABcCXgBoEAM07aVIXFygARHFEEA3ett4BKBAF4lCOxUF1XREhIjFlg1DWcAbmIEAF8omMJCFDQMa1sHBikZOSxcAmjSJhBkQVgEOgoASUQ3BBVXD3zAhHVhADpmdk4eAWEVFTobe3oGzwDmpAoWMApkHDbkCgBzAaGMyOiSGI2t+MTk9AQ04boAJglpHFl5PPHC4tLyqpq60abA1rAO1g4Qno1+oN0iN3GNNoFYFMZnMFstVsC-FFmtskbFUfcSmUZgBbHAABUopBsEAAnu4EABGU4AZj2hBYOAA7kc1vR6m0KtV6hEgA)

Since you're using `this` in an arrow function, it means `this` is the current context (`Base`) meanwhile `func` wants `Derived` as its argument. Change the method type to a normal function (that has its own context) and define `this` as `T extends Base` to satisfy func's argument.

```
abstract class Base {
  protected runFuncOnThis<T extends Base>(this: T, func: (baseOrDerived: T) => void) {
    func(this);
  };
}

class Derived extends Base {
  public doIt = () => {
    this.runFuncOnThis((derived) => {
      console.log(derived);
    });
  };
}

class Derived2 extends Base {
  public doIt = () => {
    this.runFuncOnThis((derived) => {
      console.log(derived);
    });
  };
  public someProperty = 123;
}
```

Comment: I forgot about context, thanks. But in my real case I have multiple classes deriving from Base. What type will I give 'this' and 'baseOrDerived' in the base function then? Seems like the second example is more relevant in this case.

Comment: @Tsury sorry for the misunderstanding, I've updated my answer